# In a CLI gem where do I store third-party binary executables?

Tags: ruby, binary, rubygems, command-line-interface

It seems like executables for a gem are generally stored in the `/bin` folder and all code is stored in the `/lib` folder. I have some third-party binary executables that I need to include in my gem. Should I put them in the `/bin` or the `/lib` folder?

From what I've seen the `/bin` folder is more for system executables, or scripts that I want my system to be able to call from the command-line. So I'm not sure if I should include the third-party binaries in the `/bin` folder. They need to be called as needed from the `/lib` code and not from the command-line.

I suppose I could place them in a `/lib/binaries` folder. Subsequently, is there a best practice for calling those executables from within my code?

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more? What kind of third party libraries are you talking about?

Comment: I'd recommend not including the third-party binaries, but having the user install them separately as prerequisites of running your code. That is common practice for many other gems and gives the user the chance to investigate what is being required. It also gives them the chance of using one copy for all things that need it, rather than your code having its own private copy with other possible duplicates elsewhere on the system, with possibly different version numbers. *I* would NOT be happy having unknown binaries sprinkled around my systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking you do not want to include "third party executables" with your app; ideally if they are RubyGems, you can just depend on them in your gemspec.

That being said, assuming you have a good reason to do so, you can ensure they are distributed in your RubyGem by:

- Placing them in `bin`
- Ensuring that they are included in the `files` attribute in your gemspec
- Ensuring that they are included in the `executables` attribute in your gemspec
- Ensuring that `bindir` is set.

So, if you have
    /
    /bin
    /bin/your_app
    /bin/other_app
    /bin/other_app2
    /lib/your_app.rb

You gemspec will need to look like this:

```
spec = Gem::Specification.new do |s| 
  s.name = 'your_app'
  s.version = '1.2.3'
  s.author = 'Your'
  s.email = 'your@email.com'
  s.platform = Gem::Platform::RUBY
  s.summary = 'Your app summary'
  s.description = 'Your app description`
  s.files         = [
    'bin/your_app',
    'bin/other_app',
    'bin/other_app2',
    'lib/your_app.rb',
  ]
  s.executables   = ["your_app","other_app","other_app2"]
  s.require_paths = ["lib"]
  s.bindir = 'bin'
end
```

When a user installs your app via RubyGems, the three executables will be in their path.

Comment: This was very helpful. Everything is working well except for one small problem. One of my executables, kindlegen (a binary for mac cli), is failing with "invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)". I can call bin/kindlegen directly from within the gem's absolute path location, but when the gem itself executes it, I get the error.

Comment: Solved this with a workaround. There is something about how Gem.bin_path executes files in /bin that caused the encoding failure when calling the binary directly. I just create a file in /bin that called the binary with system(). Seems to work.